# Apache Alias redirect error (only in Windows phone)

Tags: apache-2.2, alias

I have this in my apache2 config.

```
    ServerName      example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/
    Alias /m /var/www/example.com/
```

The weird thing is I can have this alias plays out nicely in all major browsers(Chrome,FF, Safari), but it's not working and hitting an internal server error 500 using IEMobile in Windows Phone 8.0

This is in my /var/apache2/log/access.log and nothing fishy appears in the error.log though.

> 192.168.10.254 - - [17/Jul/2014:23:22:10 +0800] "GET /m/ HTTP/1.1" 500 1350 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows Phone 8.0;
>   Trident/6.0; IEMobile/10.0; ARM; Touch; NOKIA; Lumia 820)"

And below I am using Chrome Mobile to access the exact same url.

> 192.168.10.254 - - [17/Jul/2014:23:23:10 +0800] "GET /m/ HTTP/1.1" 200 144129 "http://example.com/m/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux;
>   Android 4.4.2; Nexus 5 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.141 Mobile Safari/537.36"

Any idea what might causes this problem?